# How is this a Vandermonde matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, interpolation

In my linear algebra lecture notes, it states that the following is a Vandermonde matrix:
[image]

However, this doesn't seem to align with any definitions of Vandermonde matrices (or generalised Vandermonde matrices) that I've seen online.

Can someone tell me if this is a Vandermonde matrix, and if so, how (i.e. according to what definition)?

Comment: The Vandermonde matrix is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Where have you seen this matrix?

Comment: @Sebastiao Your link gives no evidence for your comment. The wikipedia page mentions nothing about multivariate "Vandermonde matrices".

Comment: @Sebastiano This is in the context of fitting a polynomial to data. "If we have $n$ data points in a two-dimensional space $(x, y)$, we can usually fit a polynomial with $n$ coefficients. Say we have 6 data points $\mathbf{f}=\left[f_0\left(x_0, y_0\right), \ldots, f_5\left(x_5, y_5\right)\right]^T$. We can (hopefully) interpolate the data points with a polynomial of the form:
$$
f(x, y)=c_0+c_1 x+c_2 y+c_3 x y+c_4 x^2+c_5 y^2 .
$$"

Comment: @VJ123 I have understood.